# Only '-vf scale.....' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters even though no other vf present

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:02:24.643 -fflags +igndts -t 00:00:39.337 -i 1.mp4 -r 60 -c:v libx264 -copytb 1 -vf scale=-2:1080,pad=width=1920:height=1080:x=0:y=656:color=black -af afade=t=in:ss=0:d=1,afade=t=out:st='00\:00\:38.337':d=1 2.mp4
```

and I get

```
Only '-vf scale=-2:1080,pad=width=1920:height=1080:x=0:y=656:color=black' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-af afade=t=in:ss=0:d=1,afade=t=out:st='00\:00\:38.337':d=1' read, ignoring remaining -af options: Use ',' to separate filters
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be ignored. Known [bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7712) in implementation. As long as you have up to a single `-vf` and up to a single `-af`, the command parsing is fine.

Comment: From the report, it looks like a fix was committed in March 2020 (https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/60e26346626cc136521a250388b5c7015ba57138), which - I think - means it won't happen in versions 4.3 onwards.